# Adding opacity to particles in javascript?

Tags: javascript, opacity

I'm looking for some help as to how I can make the particles in this script to have an option for opacity. I've tried replacing the hex color number with an rgb with opacity, but it breaks the code.

Sorry the code is poorly formatted, but this is all I have to work with, and don't know much javascript. Thanks for any help with this.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
!function(a){var b="object"==typeof self&&self.self===self&&self||"object"==typeof global&&global.global===global&&global;"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports"],function(c){b.ParticleNetwork=a(b,c)}):"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=a(b,{}):b.ParticleNetwork=a(b,{})}(function(a,b){var c=function(a){this.canvas=a.canvas,this.g=a.g,this.particleColor=a.options.particleColor,this.x=Math.random()*this.canvas.width,this.y=Math.random()*this.canvas.height,this.velocity={x:(Math.random()-.5)*a.options.velocity,y:(Math.random()-.5)*a.options.velocity}};return c.prototype.update=function(){(this.x>this.canvas.width+20||this.x<-20)&&(this.velocity.x=-this.velocity.x),(this.y>this.canvas.height+20||this.y<-20)&&(this.velocity.y=-this.velocity.y),this.x+=this.velocity.x,this.y+=this.velocity.y},c.prototype.h=function(){this.g.beginPath(),this.g.fillStyle=this.particleColor,this.g.globalAlpha=.7,this.g.arc(this.x,this.y,1.5,0,2*Math.PI),this.g.fill()},b=function(a,b){this.i=a,this.i.size={width:this.i.offsetWidth,height:this.i.offsetHeight},b=void 0!==b?b:{},this.options={particleColor:void 0!==b.particleColor?b.particleColor:"#fff",background:void 0!==b.background?b.background:"#1a252f",interactive:void 0!==b.interactive?b.interactive:!0,velocity:this.setVelocity(b.speed),density:this.j(b.density)},this.init()},b.prototype.init=function(){if(this.k=document.createElement("div"),this.i.appendChild(this.k),this.l(this.k,{position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0,"z-index":1}),/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.background))this.l(this.k,{background:this.options.background});else{if(!/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i.test(this.options.background))return console.error("Please specify a valid background image or hexadecimal color"),!1;this.l(this.k,{background:'url("'+this.options.background+'") no-repeat center',"background-size":"cover"})}if(!/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.particleColor))return console.error("Please specify a valid particleColor hexadecimal color"),!1;this.canvas=document.createElement("canvas"),this.i.appendChild(this.canvas),this.g=this.canvas.getContext("2d"),this.canvas.width=this.i.size.width,this.canvas.height=this.i.size.height,this.l(this.i,{position:"relative"}),this.l(this.canvas,{"z-index":"20",position:"relative"}),window.addEventListener("resize",function(){return this.i.offsetWidth===this.i.size.width&&this.i.offsetHeight===this.i.size.height?!1:(this.canvas.width=this.i.size.width=this.i.offsetWidth,this.canvas.height=this.i.size.height=this.i.offsetHeight,clearTimeout(this.m),void(this.m=setTimeout(function(){this.o=[];for(var a=0;a<this.canvas.width*this.canvas.height/this.options.density;a++)this.o.push(new c(this));this.options.interactive&&this.o.push(this.p),requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))}.bind(this),500)))}.bind(this)),this.o=[];for(var a=0;a<this.canvas.width*this.canvas.height/this.options.density;a++)this.o.push(new c(this));this.options.interactive&&(this.p=new c(this),this.p.velocity={x:0,y:0},this.o.push(this.p),this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(a){this.p.x=a.clientX-this.canvas.offsetLeft,this.p.y=a.clientY-this.canvas.offsetTop}.bind(this)),this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(a){this.p.velocity={x:(Math.random()-.5)*this.options.velocity,y:(Math.random()-.5)*this.options.velocity},this.p=new c(this),this.p.velocity={x:0,y:0},this.o.push(this.p)}.bind(this))),requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))},b.prototype.update=function(){this.g.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height),this.g.globalAlpha=1;for(var a=0;a<this.o.length;a++){this.o[a].update(),this.o[a].h();for(var b=this.o.length-1;b>a;b--){var c=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.o[a].x-this.o[b].x,2)+Math.pow(this.o[a].y-this.o[b].y,2));c>120||(this.g.beginPath(),this.g.strokeStyle=this.options.particleColor,this.g.globalAlpha=(120-c)/120,this.g.lineWidth=.7,this.g.moveTo(this.o[a].x,this.o[a].y),this.g.lineTo(this.o[b].x,this.o[b].y),this.g.stroke())}}0!==this.options.velocity&&requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))},b.prototype.setVelocity=function(a){return"fast"===a?1:"slow"===a?.33:"none"===a?0:.26},b.prototype.j=function(a){return"high"===a?5e3:"low"===a?2e4:isNaN(parseInt(a,10))?1e4:a},b.prototype.l=function(a,b){for(var c in b)a.style[c]=b[c]},b});

// Initialisation

var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
var options = {
  particleColor: '#FFF',
  background: '/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/gradient-top-solo-01-with-white.jpg',
  interactive: false,
  speed: 'slow',
  density: 'high'
};
var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);
```

Comment: Please add a minimum verifiable example. The code you posted is missing lot of vital information.for example we need to know what  is "ParticleNetwork"

Comment: Sorry if I have not included everything, but that is all of the code that I have running on the page, and it is working, but doesn't have an option for opacity.

This comes from the following code: https://codepen.io/JulianLaval/pen/KpLXOO

Comment: this is not possible since the library doesn't have the feature. Even if it has the feature, the lines that connect the dots are having a different opacity. So opacity here will not make any sense.

Comment: But if you are still looking for that option, You can follow this link for the js https://github.com/srajagop/canvas-particle-network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you're using is doing validation on the color and background format.

It's only allowing hexadecimal colors (#FFF or #048CEF for instance) and image files ending with gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png.

Without this validation the script would use rgba colors the same way it uses hex colors.

This validation is done by the use of [regular expressions](https://javascript.info/regular-expressions):

```
/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i
// is validating the color
```

and

```
/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i
// is validating the file extension
```

If you want the script to allow for rgba colors you can modify the regular expression of the color by adding an [alternative](https://javascript.info/regexp-alternation) to it:

```
(^rgba?\(\s*[0-9]+\s*,\s*[0-9]+\s*,\s*[0-9]+\s*(?:,\s*[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?\s*)?\)$)
// this validates loosely rgb and rgba formats
```

@Karthick has offered you a modified script, I'm offering you the why it's not working, and how to fix it by your own means.

[Here is a good resource for validating and testing regular exressions.](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!